# Remove an object and all dependent objects

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection

I have some custom object like:

```
public class House
{
    private Roof r;
    private Wall w;
    private Floor f;

    public House()
    {
        this.r = new Roof();
        this.w = new Wall();
        this.f = new Floor();
    }
}
```

Then I create a new instance of `House` object:

```
public static void main()
{
    House h = new House();
}
```

So, now I have four objects:

- House h
- Roof r
- Wall w
- Floor f

Roof `r`, Wall `w` and Floor `f` absolutely depends on House.

So if I will delete House `h`, I want them to be removed as well.

What is the correct way to do it?

---

What if I will add this method to `House` class:

```
public void remove()
{
    this.r = null;
    this.w = null;
    this.f = null;
}
```

And when I will need to remove a House `h` with all its components write:

```
public static void main()
{
    h.remove();
    h = null;
}
```

I think this should work, but not sure.

Also, maybe there is a better way?

*And yes, there is nothing about public houses, inns etc.  :)*

Comment: If you have no active references to the House object or its contents, then all objects will be eligible for GC'ing. There's no need to set any of the fields to null.

Comment: If nothing else is maintaining a reference to these internal objects, then they will garbage collected when `House` is no longer reachable. So you should be able to de-reference house and let the garbage collector take care of the rest for you

Comment: What if they **are** referenced from somewhere else? But I want them to be removed with the removal of "parent" object.

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits Then you are out of luck, because they won't be removed before they become unreachable.

Comment: There is no point in assigning null to reference that in any case will exit scope right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can never depend on garbage collection occurring at all. Even if you call `System.gc()`, you have no guarantee that it will do anything. When the system decides to run a garbage collection, unreachable references may be collected, but if you run a small application, the collector may never run.

If you need to be notified when an object is disposed, you should use a `java.lang.ref.PhantomReference` and a `java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue`. Do not depend on `Object.finalize()`. But that does not seem to be your issue; you simply want to clean up after yourself. You should care only if your application's performance requires it.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to null out all instance variables in `House` since they are automatically garbage collected when there is no reference to the instance of `House`.

> What if they **are** referenced from somewhere else? But I want them to be removed with the removal of "parent" object.

For this you should use [weak references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference) each time you reference the objects from somewhere outside of the `House` class. This way the objects will get garbage collected when there no longer is a reference to `House`, since the only strong references pointing to them are inside of `House`.

Answer (score -1):

The solution you have given is almost correct. Once you have marked an object reference as null, then that object will be destroyed and removed from memory by the JVM garbage collector whenever that garbage collector will start running .

You can also manually instruct garbage collector to collect garbage after setting reference variables as NULL .

Comment: The object will be destroyed only if it is unreachable by any means. You cannot 'manually instruct' the garbage collector, you can only give it a hint to run. -1.